# jQuery Adding / Removing classes on a button to hide elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Trying to get a mobile footer menu (#mobile-menu) to hide / show when the floating button is clicked or tapped. I'm able to add the click event handler to the button (#mobile-footer-btn) which in turns applies a class to the menu and animates it off screen.

```
<footer id="mobile-footer">
  <div id="mobile-menu">
    <div id="mobile-footer-container">
      <div class="mobile-link">
        <a href="#" class="text-center">My Account</a>
      </div>
      <div class="mobile-link">
        <a href="#" class="text-center">Reviews</a>
      </div>
      <div class="mobile-link">
        <a href="#" class="text-center">Contact Us</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mobile-footer-close">
    <button id="mobile-footer-btn">
      <div class="mobile-btn-close">
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </button>
  </div>
</footer>
```

For whatever reason, I'm not able to remove that class and add a new class to the same ID, which would add a class to show the menu again.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // Store menu container
    var mobileMenu = '#mobile-menu';
    // Store Trigger
    var mobileBtn = '#mobile-footer-btn';

    //Trigger closing the footer menu
    $(mobileBtn).on("click", function() {
        $(mobileMenu).addClass('mobile-menu-hide');
    });

    $('.mobile-btn-close').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('is-rotating');
    });

    if($(mobileMenu).hasClass('mobile-menu-hide')) {
        $(mobileBtn).on("click", function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(mobileMenu).removeClass("mobile-menu-hide").addClass("mobile-menu-show");
        });
    }
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one on click event!  Your if condition never gets evaluated to true, therefor your `onclick` event is never triggered.  It's better to house it in one onclick event.  Here's the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // Store menu container
    var mobileMenu = '#mobile-menu';
    // Store Trigger
    var mobileBtn = '#mobile-footer-btn';

    $('.mobile-btn-close').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('is-rotating');
    });

    $(mobileBtn).on("click", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if($(mobileMenu).hasClass('mobile-menu-hide')) {
          $(mobileMenu).removeClass("mobile-menu-hide").addClass("mobile-menu-show");
        } else {
          $(mobileMenu).removeClass("mobile-menu-show").addClass("mobile-menu-hide");
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/SG8eFns91wV4adxapFDB

Even better now that I think about it: just toggle the one class that hides the menu and just use jQuery's `toggleClass` function.  Something like this:

```
$(mobileBtn).on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(mobileMenu).toggleClass('mobile-menu-hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `if` condition in the block only executes once. However, you need it to be called on every click. Hence, you need to update your code to following

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // Store menu container
    var mobileMenu = '#mobile-menu';
    // Store Trigger
    var mobileBtn = '#mobile-footer-btn';

    //Trigger closing the footer menu
    $(mobileBtn).on("click", function() {
        // moved your if block inside the click handler 
        if($(mobileMenu).hasClass('mobile-menu-hide')) {

            e.stopPropagation();
            $(mobileMenu).removeClass("mobile-menu-hide").addClass("mobile-menu-show");

        } else {        
           $(mobileMenu).addClass('mobile-menu-hide');
        }
    });

    $('.mobile-btn-close').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('is-rotating');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$(mobileBtn).on("click", function(e) { ...` code never executes and, therefore, never adds the click event handler because the menu doesn't start out as `.mobile-menu-hide`  Try this

```
$(mobileBtn).on("click", function(e) {
    if($(mobileMenu).hasClass('mobile-menu-hide')) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(mobileMenu).removeClass("mobile-menu-hide").addClass("mobile-menu-show");
    }
});
```